# cmd.transferspreadsheet is sending old excel data to access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am using cmd.transferspreadsheet in Excel VBA to import an Excel sheet into an Access Table.  Every time I run this code, the data sent to access is 1 iteration out of date.  I have zeroed in on two columns one that has a tier assignment (column 4) and one that has a string for the time and person who is submitting (column 13).  In stepping through the code, I am printing the values of these 2 columns to the immediate window.  I am doing that both by a range reference and an object reference.  Both give me the correct answer, but when I go into Access, I see the data that was there before I changed it.  What am I doing wrong?!?!?!

```
Sub SendTiersToDB()

'sends the data from this file to the access database

Dim fPathName As String
Dim dbTblTiers As String
Dim strSubmit As String
Dim tblXLTiers As ListObject
Dim strXLTiers As String
Dim appDB As New Access.Application


Set tblXLTiers = Sheet7.ListObjects(1)

fPathName = "\\MERCH\Assortment Planning\Databases\New_AP_Database.accdb"
strXLTiers = tblXLTiers.DataBodyRange.Address
dbTblTiers = "Tbl_Tiers"
   
        'Fill In Subbmission Data
         strSubmit = "Last Submitted: " & Now & " by " & Environ("username")
         tblXLTiers.ListColumns(13).DataBodyRange.Value = strSubmit
         tblXLTiers.ListColumns(13).DataBodyRange.Calculate

        'and insert the new store records
        Debug.Print "By Range " & Sheet7.Range("D2").Value
        Debug.Print "By Range " & Sheet7.Range("M2").Value
        Debug.Print "By Object " & tblXLTiers.DataBodyRange(1, 4)
        Debug.Print "By Object " & tblXLTiers.DataBodyRange(1, 13)
        appDB.OpenCurrentDatabase fPathName
        appDB.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
            TransferType:=acImport, _
            SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
            TableName:=dbTblTiers, _
            Filename:="https://theexcelfilepath/file.xlsb", _
            HasFieldNames:=True, _
            Range:=Sheet7.Name & "$" & "A1:O9277"


End Sub
```

Comment: Is the online `file.xlsb` definitely saved and up-to-date when you run the transfer? Is the posted code running in that file?

Comment: I think @TimWilliams is onto the cause: the https reference to `file.xlsb` will retrieve the last saved version of the file, not the version you've modified in memory with the submission data.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the comments!  I woke up at 4AM with the same thought.
I added a line to save the file prior to the DoCmd line, and that did the trick!

```
 'Fill In Subbmission Data
         strSubmit = "Last Submitted: " & Now & " by " & Environ("username")
         tblXLTiers.ListColumns(13).DataBodyRange.Value = strSubmit
         tblXLTiers.ListColumns(13).DataBodyRange.Calculate
         ThisWorkbook.Save

        'and insert the new store records

        appDB.OpenCurrentDatabase fPathName
        appDB.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
            TransferType:=acImport, _
            SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
            TableName:=dbTblTiers, _
            Filename:="https://theexcelfilepath/file.xlsb", _
            HasFieldNames:=True, _
            Range:=Sheet7.Name & "$" & "A1:O9277"
```